# How to disable unlock with Apple ID in Mountain Lion when FileVault is enabled?

Tags: filevault

I have a Mac with FileVault 2 enabled, and recently upgraded to Mountain Lion.

Apple automatically enables the option to unlock my system account using my Apple ID in Mountain Lion, and because I have FileVault 2 enabled also *hides* the option to disable this feature.

If I want to disable "unlock using Apple ID" I can decrypt my drive by disabling FileVault, then the option will appear again. I can then disable the option and re-encrypt my drive by enabling FileVault.

I don't want to do this: How can I disable "unlock using Apple ID" using the command line or skipping the decrypt/encrypt step?

Comment: I'm not quite clear: does enabling FileVault enable/activate the unlock using Apple ID function?

Comment: @Matt: upgrading a Lion machine (with FileVault enabled+Apple ID recovery disabled) to Mountain Lion force enables Apple ID recovery. Decrypting the disk, i.e. disabling FileVault will unhide the Apple ID recovery option and allow it to be disabled again.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with an Apple ID but in general you can add/remove users from the list using the fdesetup command. For example, to delete the user 'bill':

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user bill
```

You can use the following to see which users can unlock the disk:

```
sudo fdesetup list
```